# Why is strtotime not giving me the proper timezone conversion?

Tags: php, date, timezone, timezone-offset

My understanding is America/Los_Angeles is PDT timezone, which is 8 hours behind Zulu time, but when I run this in PHP, it seems to suggest it is -7. Could anyone help me understand what the problem is?

```
=date_default_timezone_get()
"America/Los_Angeles"

=strtotime('2017-03-16T06:00:00Z')
1489644000

=date('r', strtotime('2017-03-16T06:00:00Z'))
"Wed, 15 Mar 2017 23:00:00 -0700"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los Angeles PST (Pacific Standard Time) changes to daylight saving time PDT on 12th March, so the time difference to Zulu will change by an hour.